# Navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

I'm having a problem with the Navigator in React Native. I want to navigate to another screen when pressing some Text, but I'm getting a strange error, I'm not too sure why.

Here's my code blocks and a picture of the error I'm receiving.

```js
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import ViewContainer from '../components/ViewContainer';
import StatusBarBackground from '../components/StatusBarBackground';
import AppNavigator from '../navigation/AppNavigator'

import UserIndexScreen from './UserIndexScreen'

class LoginIndexScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ViewContainer>
                <StatusBarBackground />
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.loginText}>Welcome to</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={(event) => this._navigateToUserIndexScreen()}>
                        <Text style={styles.nextStep}>Press to go to User Index Screen</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ViewContainer>
        );
    }

    _navigateToUserIndexScreen() {
        AppNavigator.props.push({
            ident: "UserIndex"
        })
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    textContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },

    loginText: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 30
    },

    nextStep: {
        marginTop: 80
    }

});

module.exports = LoginIndexScreen;
```

And here's the Navigator component.

```js
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navigator } from 'react-native';

import RegisterIndexScreen from '../screens/RegisterIndexScreen';
import LoginIndexScreen from '../screens/LoginIndexScreen';
import UserIndexScreen from '../screens/UserIndexScreen';
import PersonProfileScreen from '../screens/PersonProfileScreen';

class AppNavigator extends Component {

    _renderScene(route, navigator) {
        var globalNavigatorProps = { navigator }

        switch(route.ident) {
            case "RegisterIndexScreen":
                return (
                    <RegisterIndexScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
                )
            case "LoginIndexScreen":
                return (
                    <LoginIndexScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
                )
            case "UserIndex":
                return (
                    <UserIndexScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
                )
            case "Temp":
                return (
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                )
            case "PersonProfileScreen":
                return (
                    <PersonProfileScreen {...globalNavigatorProps}
                    person={route.person} />
                )
            default:
                return (
                    <LoginIndexScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
                )
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={this.props.initialRoute}
                ref="appNavigator"
                renderScene={this._renderScene}
                configureScene={(route) => ({...route.sceneConfig || Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight, })} />
        );
    }

}

module.exports = AppNavigator;
```

Also here's a picture of the error I'm receiving:

[image: React Native Error]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You are trying to invoke a child component method in parent.
2. Method you are trying to invoke is not a part of your child component, you are calling RN Navigator method.
3. You should use navigator object that you passed to view in navigator renderScene function.

So in general you want to do sth. like:

In AppNavigator's _renderScene function pass navigator object:

```
<LoginIndexScreen nv={navigator} />
```

Then in LoginIndexScreen's _navigateToUserIndexScreen function use passed nv props:

```
this.props.nv.push({ ident: "UserIndex" })
```

You should also bind functions. Check https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a bit confused with what you mean by passing the navigator object in the _renderScene function. I tried putting that into the renderScene function, but would hit an error. Could you explain a bit further? Thanks!

Comment: Your render view function handles "what is currently on the display" (scenes). In this function you return a view based on what is on top of the navigator routes stack. So when you are returning LoginIndexScreen you should pass (as props) an instance of navigator object (to let you use it in rendered scenes). Navigator instance is a argument of renderScene function.